# Speeding up a linq query with 40,000 rows

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

In my service, first I generate 40,000 possible combinations of home and host countries, like so (`clientLocations` contains 200 records, *so 200 x 200 is 40,000*):

```
foreach (var homeLocation in clientLocations)
{
    foreach (var hostLocation in clientLocations)
    {
        allLocationCombinations.Add(new AirShipmentRate
        {
            HomeCountryId = homeLocation.CountryId,
            HomeCountry = homeLocation.CountryName,
            HostCountryId = hostLocation.CountryId,
            HostCountry = hostLocation.CountryName,
            HomeLocationId = homeLocation.LocationId,
            HomeLocation = homeLocation.LocationName,
            HostLocationId = hostLocation.LocationId,
            HostLocation = hostLocation.LocationName,
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I run the following query to find existing rates for the locations above, but also include empty the missing rates; resulting in a complete recordset of 40,000 rows.

```
var allLocationRates = (from l in allLocationCombinations
                        join r in Db.PaymentRates_AirShipment
                            on new { home = l.HomeLocationId, host = l.HostLocationId }
                            equals new { home = r.HomeLocationId, host = (Guid?)r.HostLocationId }
                        into matches
                        from rate in matches.DefaultIfEmpty(new PaymentRates_AirShipment
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                        })
                        select new AirShipmentRate
                        {
                            Id = rate.Id,
                            HomeCountry = l.HomeCountry,
                            HomeCountryId = l.HomeCountryId,
                            HomeLocation = l.HomeLocation,
                            HomeLocationId = l.HomeLocationId,
                            HostCountry = l.HostCountry,
                            HostCountryId = l.HostCountryId,
                            HostLocation = l.HostLocation,
                            HostLocationId = l.HostLocationId,
                            AssigneeAirShipmentPlusInsurance = rate.AssigneeAirShipmentPlusInsurance,
                            DependentAirShipmentPlusInsurance = rate.DependentAirShipmentPlusInsurance,
                            SmallContainerPlusInsurance = rate.SmallContainerPlusInsurance,
                            LargeContainerPlusInsurance = rate.LargeContainerPlusInsurance,
                            CurrencyId = rate.RateCurrencyId
                        });
```

I have tried using `.AsEnumerable()` and `.AsNoTracking()` and that has sped things up quite a bit.  **The following code shaves several seconds off of my query:**

```
var allLocationRates = (from l in allLocationCombinations.AsEnumerable()
                        join r in Db.PaymentRates_AirShipment.AsNoTracking()
```

But, I am wondering:  How can I speed this up even more?

**Edit:**  Can't replicate `foreach` functionality in linq.

```
allLocationCombinations = (from homeLocation in clientLocations
                            from hostLocation in clientLocations
                            select new AirShipmentRate
                            {
                                HomeCountryId = homeLocation.CountryId,
                                HomeCountry = homeLocation.CountryName,
                                HostCountryId = hostLocation.CountryId,
                                HostCountry = hostLocation.CountryName,
                                HomeLocationId = homeLocation.LocationId,
                                HomeLocation = homeLocation.LocationName,
                                HostLocationId = hostLocation.LocationId,
                                HostLocation = hostLocation.LocationName
                            });
```

I get an error on `from hostLocation in clientLocations` which says "cannot convert type IEnumerable to Generic.List."

Comment: Can the entire query be run server-side?  For example, your first loop is basically a manual implementation of a `CROSS JOIN` in SQL, and would be much more efficiently executed by your database engine.

Comment: That's a good idea; I could try something like that.  I just didn't know if the `foreach` would be faster or not.

Comment: Do you keep data in `clientLocations` in your database?

Comment: @mellamokb I tried doing a cross join (question edited with code) but I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: @tia Yes, I `clientLocations` is in the database, but I must also get all possible combinations of client locations, so I have to do the foreach.

Comment: @user1477388: I think it's because you have already defined your variable `allocationCombinations` to be a `List`.  If you say for example `var myResult1 = (from homeLocation...` it should work.

Comment: Regardless, the point is you want the logic to be executed server-side, not client-side.  Whether you write it as `from ... from ...` or as a nested `foreach` loop is irrelevant - one is just syntactic sugar for the other.  If you start with your database schema, it should be possible to write a single SQL Select statement that gets the result.  Then converting that from SQL to LINQ should be relatively straightforward, and very fast if the database does the entire execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I speed this up even more?

Optimizing is a ***bitch***.

Your code looks fine to me. Make sure to set the index on your DB schema where it's appropriate. And as already mentioned: Run your Linq against SQL to get a better idea of the performance.

---

**Well, but how to improve *performance* anyway?**

You may want to have a glance at the following link:
[10 tips to improve LINQ to SQL Performance](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html)

To me, probably the most important points listed (in the link above):

- Retrieve Only the Number of Records You Need
- Turn off ObjectTrackingEnabled Property of Data Context If Not
  Necessary
- Filter Data Down to What You Need Using DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith
- Use compiled queries when it's needed (please be careful with that one...)

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to query a database is to use the power of the database engine itself.

While Linq is a fantastic technology to use, it still generates a select statement out of the Linq query, and runs this query against the database.

Your best bet is to create a database View, or a stored procedure.

Views and stored procedures can easily be integrated into Linq.

Material Views ( in MS SQL ) can further speed up execution, and missing indexes are by far the most effective tool in speeding up database queries.